# Finding array length in function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a function that returns the length of an array in C++,
So far I made the function:

```
int solution(int A[]) { return (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
```

But I'm given the error: Dividing sizeof a pointer by another value,

Comment: `template <std::size_t N>int solution(int (&A)[N]) { return N; }`?

Comment: Switch to a `std::vector` or `std::array` then just use `.size()`